# How to resolve IndexError in python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to bin z over x and y, but I get `IndexError: index 50 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 50` at the line `sum[y_i,x_i] = sum[y_i,x_i] + z[0][i]` ..

I've tried to  resolve this issue by adding negative 1 in `for i in range(pts-1):` but it didn't work. Any support on this will be greatly appreciated.

Here is the Error Output I'm getting:

```
IndexError  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-51245b26f0b5> in <module>
     43             x_i = x_inds[0][i]
     44             y_i = y_inds[0][i]
---> 45             sum[y_i,x_i] = sum[y_i,x_i] + z[0][i]
     46             num[y_i,x_i] = num[y_i,x_i] + 1
     47 

IndexError: index 50 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 50
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error setting up arrays. The value of x_inds[14] is 50. If you want to get the 50th value on the x-axis of the sum array, you have to write the sum [y][49]. Since the sum array has 50 elements, when you type sum [y][50], you try to get the 51st element, so you get an error. It worked when I did it as follows.

```
for i in range(pts):
    x_i = x_inds[i] -1
    y_i = y_inds[i] -1
    print(str(x_i) + " " + str(y_i) )
    sum[y_i][x_i] = sum[y_i][x_i] + z[i]
    num[y_i][x_i] = num[y_i][x_i] + 1
```

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation, it totally makes sense. When I re-ran my code with the code snippet of yours, I get "IndexError: index 35 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 17", thats very weird, not sure what does this mean, any idea? - Thank you

Comment: I did not define x like you, it may be because of this. I defined it as x = [267.25, 268.06, ...]. I think you defined it as x = [[267.25, 268.06, ...]]. So it may have to be x_i = x_inds [0][i] -1 on your code. The same is true for y and z of course.

Comment: I cannot thank you any enough! this worked beautifully! tbh I wasn't aware that depending on the way we define our variables we might need to do some adjustments to match too. Thank you once again :)